# KnockoutJS, Rails and Pagination: data-bind is only applied on the first page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, knockout.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using KnockoutJS in Rails 4 with will_paginate gem. Things are working OK, except for 1 binding.

```
<span data-bind="attr: { class: setLabelColor('<%= log.environment_name %>') }"><%= log.environment_name %></span>
```

This applies label color depending on the environment name

```
self.setLabelColor = function(env) {
    if (env == 'dev') {
        return 'label label-success'
    } else if (env == 'stage') {
        return 'label label-warning'
    } else if (env == 'prod') {
        return 'label label-important'
    }

}
```

For some reason the binding above is only applied on the initial page. When I click Next/Previous buttons it changes the page, generates the HTML table, but the binding is not applied and element does not get correct class applied.

My viewModel is applied to the entire DOM, but this one particular table generated by Rails and not KO and only has a single binding in every row. If i reload the page, binding gets applied as expected.

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Is this a TurboLinks problem?

Comment: @muistooshort: hmm... i do have turbolinks enabled... do you think this is what causing it?

Comment: @muistooshort: you were right! Installing jquery-turbolinks solved this issue. Thank you so much! I spent 3 hours trying to troubleshoot this. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark this question as solved? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails4 and "it only works on the initial page" smells like a TurboLinks problem. TurboLinks is enabled by default in Rails4 and [TurboLinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#turbolinks):

> [...] makes following links in your web application faster. Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head. Think CGI vs persistent process.

In short, it turns a traditional multi-page application into a single page application. Along the way, `$(document).ready(...)` is broken because the document-ready handlers are only called when loading the initial page (since that's the only page that gets loaded).

A few solutions:

1. Turn off TurboLinks if you don't want or need it.
2. Use `page:change` events instead of document-ready events to initialize all your page stuff.
3. Install [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks), that should fix up most of your `$(document).ready(...)` calls without further intervention.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you. The way i got it fixed is by installing `jquery-turbolinks` as described here: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#jqueryturbolinks